# Sending compressed responses in vert.x

Tags: vert.x

I have a RESTful server that sends back to client large chunks of JSON. I had implemented the server in Grails, and to do some benchmarking I've rewrote it in vert.x.

Everything works, besides gzip compression, I haven't found a way to activate it in vert.x
I've searched for an answer in vert.x site, here and in Google, and I wasn't able to find any info, so I try to get an answer by posting here :)

Is there anyway to gzip responses on vert.x?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've found the answer to my own question...

In vert.x 2.1M1 they have added HTTP compression to `HttpServer` and `DefaultHttpServer`. To activate it, you must use the method `setCompressionSupported(true)`.

It didn't seemed to work for me, even if I used vert.x 2.1M1. It was because I am using Groovy, and vert.x  mod-lang-groovy hasn't been updated since version 2.0.0.

So Java vert.x libs allow compression but Groovy libs that wrap Java ones don't. The `setCompressionSupported(true)` method gave me a NotSuchMethod exception.

I found a workaround. I use `toJavaServer()` method to recover the Java HttpServer inside the Groovy one, and I call `setCompressionSupported(true)` on this Java HttpServer.

And now I have HTTP compression in my Groovy verticles :)

Answer (score 12):

The compression support in VertX 3.x was slightly modified.

Now it can be turned on via (Java example):

```
HttpServerOptions serverOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
serverOptions.setCompressionSupported(true);
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions);
```